# shortest distance of convex polygon with start and exit problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I've been asked the following question:
You have N points, where two of them are the "start" and "exit"
You want to start at "start", go through every other node, and end up at "exit". What is the shortest path (using Euclidean distance) if the polygon formed by the N nodes is convex? Is there a better algorithm than brute force here?

edit1:

It was a problem asked in TAP in 2016 (Argentinian Programming Competition) and it was mentioned to me today. I suspect there must be a better than bruteforce algorithm here using the convexity property otherwise they woudn't ask it on a competition. Also the constraints for N were N < 400 so it wound't be solvable with a O(n!) solution

edit2:

One interesting case is this one:
Consider a very long and narrow rectangle, where the points are on the long sides of the rectangle, one in front of the other.
The start and exit points are on the opposite ends of this "tunnel"
doing a clockwise or counterclockwise turn you would end up travelling 2*L where L is the size of the long side of the rectangle.
Doing a zig-zag from start to end would be optimal here, since you only need to go through L once, and then some small steps from one side to the other.

Comment: If you want help with a homework question, you need to show some effort here. Do you suspect there is a better algorithm than brute force? What would it be like?

Comment: @Turnsole Not a homework question. It was a problem asked in TAP in 2016 (Argentinian Programming Competition) and it was mentioned to me today. I suspect there must be a better than bruteforce algorithm here using the convexity property otherwise they woudn't ask it on a competition. Also the constraints for N were N < 400 so it wound't be solvable with a O(n!) solution

Comment: Then you should edit your question description so that it does not seem that the question is a homework.

Comment: You can find an algorithm with O(log n) complexity. Hint: Newton downhill and binary search

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a better algorithm than brute force here?**

If you think this problem with **dynamic programming** you can get a solution *O(n^2)* that is possible to solve constraint for the constraint *n < 400*.

This link has a good explication, see problem B: https://caloventorendos.blogspot.com/2016/09/solucionario-tap-2016.html